# PHP SoapClient Timeout in Different Enviroments

Tags: php, web-services, soap, zend-framework, request

I'm working in **two differents enviroments**, in **local machine** and **production**.
I did a soap request using soap ui with local url and request looks great (after 4/5min), that's not happen in production (with production url), after 2min a get a message "connection reset".

```
$soap = new Zend_Soap_Server ( $url_wsdl, 
                                array (
                                    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
                                    'trace' => true, 
                                    'connection_timeout' => 300, "use" => SOAP_ENC_ARRAY,
                                    'encoding' => 'ISO8859-1',
                                    'ssl' => array(
                                                // set some SSL/TLS specific options
                                                'verify_peer' => false,
                                                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                                                'allow_self_signed' => true
                                            )
                                      )
                              );
```

I check some timeouts and php.ini and i didn't found not wrong. Anyone have some idea to help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Do not switch SSL verification off! See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14361903/1839439

Comment: @Dharman i think is not the same problem, i can get results if i add more parameters to request.